# Why is my function not deleting all numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, char, numbers

I made a function that will find any digits in an array and remove them. Here's my code:

```
int noNums (char *a) {
  int i;
  int deleteInd;
  for (i = 0; (i < MAX_NAME_SZ) && (a[i] != '\0'); i++) {
      if ((a[i] >= '0') && (a[i] <= '9')) {
      deleteInd = i;
      memmove (&a[deleteInd], &a[deleteInd + 1], strlen (a) - deleteInd);
      }
  }
}
```

If a number is by itself in the char array, then it is removed, no problem. However, if there are consecutive numbers in the array, then only every other digit will be deleted?

If my char array has

> w12345678

then the array is changed to

> w2468

instead of

> w

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't like the `&a[deleteInd]` notation very much (don't get me wrong, it is correct), but I prefer `a + deleteInd`, for me it's more elegant. For me, this `memmove (a + deleteInd, a + deleteInd + 1, strlen (a) - deleteInd);` is so much easier to read.

Comment: About the skipping, you can do `i--` in after `memmove` which would mean that you repeat the same index.

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you do the `memmove()`, the next element is now in the index of the element you just deleted. But your loop will do `i++`, so you won't check that index again. As a result, whenever there are two digits in a row, you skip the second one.

One way to fix this is to loop from the end of the array to the beginning, instead of from the beginning to the end.

Another way is to do `i--` after doing the `memmove()`, to counteract the `i++` that the loop will do.

```
  if (isdigit(a[i]) {
      deleteInd = i;
      memmove (&a[deleteInd], &a[deleteInd + 1], strlen (a) - deleteInd);
      i--;
  }
```

BTW, you should use `isdigit()` to test whether a character is a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that you are deleting the first digit then skipping one?

When iterating through the array, you start at position 0 and incrementing.  When you delete a digit, you alter the string index.

```
i = 0 (char = w)
Index:  012345689
string: w12345678

i = 1 (char = 1)
Index:  012345689
string: w2345678

i = 2 (char = 3)
Index:  012345689
string: w2345678
```

Essentially, you are shifting the string over whenever you delete your character.

Don't increment i when you delete a character.

Note that deleteInd is not needed in your code, you could use i directly.

Comment: Yeah, just realized :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer — [Barmar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50033468/1475978) is — but both this and OP's [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032662/remove-identical-consecutive-lines-in-a-char-array-in-c) shows they could use a fresh look into how to modify character arrays in place.

This is written in the hopes that this is useful to others learning C as well.

---

Elements, or sequences of elements, can be removed from an array efficiently, using a simple loop over its contents.

The key is to keep two indexes: one for the next element (or elements) to be examined, and one for the last element stored (or the next position to store to).

For example, to remove digits in an array, one can use the following pseudocode function:

```
Function removedigits(array, length):
    Let  i = 0      # Index of next element to examine, "input"
    Let  o = 0      # Position of next element to store, "output"

    While (i < length):
        If (array[i] is not a digit):
            Let  array[o] = array[i]
            Let  o = o + 1
        End If
        Let  i = i + 1
    End While

    # For a string, we'll also want to terminate the array
    # at o, because the rest of it contains garbage (old contents):
    Let  array[o] = '\0'
End Function
```

When dealing with sequences, it may be useful to keep multiple indexes. For example, to remove duplicate lines, one might use the following function:

```
Function removeduplicatelines(array):
    Let  i = 0         # Next position in the array to be examined
    Let  o = 0         # Next position in the array to store to
    Let  ostarted = 0  # Index at which the last line stored started at

    # Loop over each input line:
    While (array[i] != '\0'):

        # Find the length of this line. It can end with a newline
        # or at the end of the string. The newline is not included.
        Let  ilen = 0
        While (array[i + ilen] != '\n' && array[i + ilen] != '\0'):
            Let  ilen = ilen + 1
        End While

        # If the already stored line is of different length
        # (the +1 is for the newline, as it is not included in ilen)
        # or if it does not match the input line, store input line.
        If (ostarted + ilen + 1 != o || memcmp(array + ostarted, array + i, ilen) != 0):
            # The lengths or content differs. Store the line.

            # Copy ilen characters, starting at array[i],
            # to array[o] onwards.
            # Because the array parts do not overlap,
            # we can safely use memcpy() here.
            memcpy(array + o, array + i, ilen)

            # It is now the last stored line.
            Let  ostarted = o
            Let  o = o + ilen

            # If there is a newline following the line,
            # store that too.
            If (array[i + ilen] == '\n'):
                Let  array[o] = '\n'
                Let  o = o + 1
            End If

        Else:
            # It is the same line again. Do not store.
        End If

        # Proceed to the next input line.
        Let  i = i + ilen

        # Because the newline was not included in ilen,
        # skip it if there is one.
        If (array[i] == '\n'):
            Let  i = i + 1
        End If

    End While

    # After index o, the array may contain old contents;
    # so terminate the string at index o.
    Let  array[o] = '\0'
End Function
```

Note that `memcmp()` returns zero, if the `ilen` characters starting at `array + ostarted` match those starting at `array + i`.

This approach works, if we know `o` never exceeds `i`; that is, that we never overwrite array contents we haven't examined yet. But do note that `o` is allowed to be equal to `i`, as that just means we overwrite the same character we just examined, making no actual change in the array.

If we wanted to modify the function so that it skips empty lines, we add a new while loop before the existing one, to remove any leading newlines:

```
While (array[i] == '\n'):
    Let  i = i + 1
End While
```

and, to remove any empty lines, we modify the last part within the while loop into

```
        # Because the newline was not included in ilen,
        # skip it (and any additional newlines) if there is one.
        While (array[i] == '\n'):
            Let  i = i + 1
        End While
```

Finally, do note that the above `removeduplicatelines()` is very careful about not appending a newline after the last line, if there isn't one in the array to begin with.