# In C, how do I remove identical, and consecutive lines in a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm looking for some help in creating a function.

The funciton, deleteIdents(), will remove identical lines in a char array, given they are consecutive. It will keep one of the identical lines.

I don't need to check if the whole line is identical. Just the first 79 chars, MAXCHARS, will be fine for this scenario.

So, for example, if my array contains

```
Hello World
Hi World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hi there
```

it will be changed to

```
Hello World
Hi World
Hello World
Hi there
```

In my head, the function would look similar to:

```
int deleteIdents(char *a)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=MAXCHARS; i++) {
        if (a[i] != '\n')
            /* copy into new array */
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm unsure. If you have a solution, I'd be glad and thankful to hear it :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like a homework question.

Comment: It's a sub function of a bigger program I'm working on.  I've been trying with a while statement, and still working on that.

Comment: Can you show us this while statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove identical, consecutive lines in a char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032662/remove-identical-consecutive-lines-in-a-char-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Well read first line than second, compare them if they are equal go into the loop until they are not equal. So here is code:

```
char *first_line = malloc(MAXLINE);
char *second_line = malloc(MAXLINE);

getline(first_line);

do {
   getline(second_line);
} while (strcmp (first_line, second_line));
```

For `getline()` implementation search SO there are plenty of examples. Or [here](https://github.com/goranvel/KandR/blob/master/ch5/exercises/e5-11_detab.c) you have mine.

Comment: Suggest `char *first_line;` --> `char first_line[79 + 2];`  Likewise for `second_line`

Comment: ending with null, that's why

Comment: 79 because "Just the first 79 chars".  + 1 for the _null character_ and +1 for the `'\n'` (which  may apply to `getline`), so `[79 + 1 /* + 1 */]`

Answer (score 0):

Another example how it can be achived. Idea is to keep 2 pointers, and increment first one only if entries are different. Also some additional storage is allocated to avoid memory leaks for entries that has been overriden.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int unique(char **strings, int size) {
    if (!strings) {
        return -1;
    }
    int head = 0, newHead = 0, duplicatedElementsHead = 0;
    //Save duplicates to avoid memory leaks
    char** duplicatedEntries = malloc(size*sizeof(char*));

    while (head < size) {
        //String are the same
        if (!strcmp(strings[head], strings[newHead])) {
            if (head != newHead) {
                duplicatedEntries[duplicatedElementsHead++] = strings[newHead];
            }
            ++head;
        } else {
            strings[++newHead] = strings[head++];
        }
    }

    //Put duplicated entries after new end
    int idx = 0, tmpHead = newHead + 1;
    for (; idx < duplicatedElementsHead; ++idx) {
        strings[tmpHead++] = duplicatedEntries[idx];
    }

    free(duplicatedEntries);
    return newHead;
}

int main() {
    char **strings = malloc(8*sizeof(char*));
    strings[0] = "Hello World";
    strings[1] = "Hi World";
    strings[2] = "Hi World";
    strings[3] = "Hello World";
    strings[4] = "Hello World";
    strings[5] = "Hi there";
    strings[6] = "Hia";
    strings[7] = "Hi";
    int newEnd = unique(strings, 8);
    for (int i=0; i < newEnd; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    free(strings);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are essentially writing the core functionality of the unix/linux utility, 'uniq'.

```
cat filename | sort | uniq > newfile
#or skip sort, since you didn't mention
cat filename | uniq > newfile
```

You could just use popen and uniq (something like this...)

```
FILE *uniqfh;
uniqfh = popen("cat file1 | uniq" , "r");
if (uniqfh == NULL) { //handle error
}
while( fgets(uniqfh, buffer, buffersize) ) printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

But seriously, you could write the core of uniq(),

```
static long MAXUNIQ=79; //or whatever you want
char*
isdup(char* prev, char* next, long len)
{
    //if( !prev || !next) error
    long n = len<=0 ? MAXUNIQ : len;
    for(  ; *prev==*next && n --> 0; ) { //down-to operator (sic)
        ; //clearly nothing happening here!
    }
    return( (n<1) || !(*p+*n) );
}
/yeah, this is actually strncmp, but hey
```

You need an array of 'strings' (char* or char[]), let's read them,

```
char* ray[ARRAYMAX]; //define how many elements of your arRay
//could use, char** ray; and malloc(ARRAYMAX*sizeof(char*))

long
read_array(FILE* fh, char* ray[])
{
    char buffer[MAXLINE+1];
    long count=0;
    while( fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fh) ) {
        //you could eat dups here, or in separate function below
        //if( (count<1) && !isdup(ray[count-1],buffer,MAXUNIQ) )
        ray[count++] = strdup(buffer);
    }
    //ray[0] through ray[count-1] contain char*
    //count contains number of strings read
    return count;
}
long
deleteIdents(long raysize, char* ray[]) //de-duplicate
{
    long kept, ndx;
    for( ndx=1, kept=0; ndx<raysize; ++ndx ) {
        if( !isdup(ray[kept],ray[ndx]) ) {
            ray[kept++] = ray[ndx];
        }
        else {
            free(ray[ndx]);
            ray[ndx] = NULL; //not entirely necessary, 
        }
    }
    return kept; //new ray size
}
```

And you will need to to this to call it...

```
...
long raysize;
char* ray[ARRAYMAX] = {0}; //init to null pointers
raysize = read_array(fopen(filename,"r"),ray);
raysize = deleteIndents(raysize,ray);
...
```

Later, you will need to free the malloc'ed strings,

```
for( ; 0 <-- raysize; ) { free(ray[raysize]);  ray[raysize] = NULL; }
```

Comment: Yeah, the raysize/count/kept/ndx should be size_t, but are you really going to keep an array of > 2 billion strings in memory? Ok, servers already have 256-512GB memory, so use size_t.

Comment: You don't check array capacity on reading the file.... you can leak it.

Comment: the question was to eliminate adjacent duplicates in an array.  Did you read? **an array**.  PO doesn't mention a file.... Are you obsessed with remaking the `uniq(1)` tool?

Comment: Also, in case you want the functionality of the `uniq(1)` you don't need more than space to read just *two* lines: the ones you are going to compare.  In case they are equal, you don't do anything, but read another line, in case they are different, you output both lines, discard the first, copy the second into the first, and read one more line.  When you are finished and cannot read any more lines, you output the contents of the line you have, and you are finished.

Comment: The OP did not pass an array to his function, I wanted to illustrate how to populate and read an array of strings for their benefit. And no, I would not have implemented uniq using an array. And the answer uses his function, and fixes the function signature.

Answer (score -1):

The following program does what you need on an array of string elements.  We navigate the array with two pointers, initialised to the first and second elements.  We run a loop of `array_n - 1` comparisons of one element to the next one, comparing both strings... if they are different, we copy the `*source_ptr` string pointer to the `*target_ptr` place.  If they are different we only increment the `source_ptr`, so it points to the next array string, but *without copying it* (this makes us to effectively delete the pointer)  We are also managing the new array (we have used the same array as source and destination, as we can only delete array elements, so each time we have a greater hole between both pointers)

## pru.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* array of strings */    
char *array[] = {
    "Hello World",
    "Hi World",
    "Hello World",
    "Hello World",
    "Hello World",
    "Hi there",
};

size_t array_n = sizeof array / sizeof *array;

int main()
{
    int i;

    char **target_ptr = array, **source_ptr = array + 1;
    size_t new_length = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < array_n; i++) {
        /* if strings pointed to by pointers are equal */
        if (strcmp(*target_ptr, *source_ptr) == 0) {
            /* go to the next, effectively discarding the second pointer */
            source_ptr++;
        } else {
            /* copy both pointers in place, to the destination array */
            *target_ptr++ = *source_ptr++;
            new_length++; /* increment array length */
        }
    }
    /* finally, we have in the array only the good pointers */

    /* print'em */
    for (i = 0; i < new_length; i++)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);

    exit(0);
}
```

and that's all.

## sample run:

```
$ pru
Hi World
Hello World
Hi there
Hello World
$ _
```